# Encryption software trustworthy?

Tags: encryption, trust, backdoor

If you are downloading and using  an encryption software, e. g. Veracrypt or Diskcryptor, how do you know if this software is not a fake one? Backdoored or other security holes? Assuming that such programs are not coded within a rainy sunday afternoon by a nitwit, manpower is required, but they are free! Even if it is open source, most users have neither knowledge nor time to check the code. 
What is your way to be sure  to be on the right track?
Thank you very much for your advice and suggestions!

Comment: `most users have neither knowledge nor time to check the code.` If the software is popular enough, you would hope that at least _some_ of the people using it want to _ensure_ the software will do what it says on the tin rather than relying on what the maintainer of the project tells them. Because of this simple fact, and the fact _anyone_ can read the code for flaws and raise them to the maintainer of the project, often the more popular the software is the more secure it is because this creates a positive feedback loop within the open source community.

Answer (score 5):

When the software is popular, security-relevant and open source (like Veracrypt), then there will often be people who will audit it and report vulnerabilities. VeraCrypt is based on TrueCrypt 7.1, which [got a comprehensive audit a while ago](https://opencryptoaudit.org/). Many open source projects also got public bugtrackers where known bugs are reported.

But when you download your copy of the program from an untrusted mirror, you can not be sure that it is compiled from the original sourcedcode. That's why many projects publish cryptographic checksums or PGP signatures to verify that the files served by the mirrors are identical to the official builds. When you look at [the download site from VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Downloads), for example, you will notice that they have a public PGP key and a PGP signature for each of their downloads. You can use [GnuPG](https://www.gnupg.org/) to verify these files.

But when the sourcecode of a software is **not** available, then all proof you have that it does not have vulnerabilities (whether intentional or unintentional) is the word of the developer (and maybe that of any 3rd parties they gave the sourcecode to for review). That's why some security professionals do not recommend to use closed source security products.

Answer (score 0):

You don't trust software, you trust people. What system do you use? Windows? So, if Microsoft wanted they could control your PC easily. Maybe they don't have a direct back-door in the system yet, but it's just a question of the "security update" you would install.

Do you have a mobile phone? Android? Then Google can do the same with your mobile phone. Do you use Linux? Ubuntu? Canonical is the company you have to trust. With Debian you would have to trust an association of people who care about Debian.

Do you trust people who maintain Vearacrypt? You can download Veracrypt from their pages, you can check the SSL certificate which is signed by an authority. So, additionally you have to trust the authority.

You can download the source code. Well, it's much easier to check the source code than binary. However, it has thousands of lines of code and it would takes you years to check it properly. And even if you check the code, did you check the compiler? Also, the system (windows) must have access to your encryption key when your disk is mounted. And what about the CPU (made by Intel)? Did you check that?

The only thing you can do is that you can reduce the number of subjects you have to trust. For instance, you can use only the products made by Apple. Your life would be in Apple's hands, but what's important is that it would be in Apple's hands only... I don't recommend that :-).

Comment: The issue with this is that the code in question is open source. If they inserted a back door, it would be easily spotted and assumingly a lynch mob against the developer(s) would ensue. Also, thousands of lines of code would not take years to audit, especially by a professional team. As for for hardware/close source software vendors though, this certainly has merit.

Comment: Ok, then you have to trust the "professional team". And what the hell it means "professional team"? Do you know the people or have you just read someone was payed for the audit? BTW, do you really think it is so difficult to hide a back-door to the source code? So naive...